# Add Digital Signature to PDF using iTextSharp - SmartCard Certificate (PIN Protected)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, smartcard

I use the following code to sign PDF document but I always end up with a certificate that is not valid.

```
private void SignWithThisCert(X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
string SourcePdfFileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\Document.pdf";
string DestPdfFileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\Document.Signed.pdf";
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData) };

IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA256");
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SourcePdfFileName);
FileStream signedPdf = new FileStream(DestPdfFileName, FileMode.Create);  //the output pdf file
PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, signedPdf, '\0');
PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;

signatureAppearance.Reason = "Safe Document";
signatureAppearance.Location = "My place";            

signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION;
MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
//MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
pdfStamper.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

}

Then I just call this method:

```
//Sign from SmartCard
//note : ProviderName and KeyContainerName can be found with the dos command : CertUtil -ScInfo
string ProviderName = "cv act sc/interface CSP";
string KeyContainerName = "12345e02a1dcb12ece12345f0e203c093eb2f0ef";
string PinCode = "MYPINCODE";
if (PinCode != "")
{
    //if pin code is set then no windows form will popup to ask it
    SecureString pwd = GetSecurePin(PinCode);
    CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1,
                    ProviderName,
            KeyContainerName,
            new System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeySecurity(),
            pwd);
    try
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
                // the pin code will be cached for next access to the smart card
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("Crypto error: " + ex.Message);
                return;
    }
}
var cert = Helper.GetCertBySubject("cert subject here");
SignWithThisCert(cert);
```

And it signs the signature to the PDF document but when I open it in reader it says that the certificate is not valid.

I am using a PIN protected smartcard with non-exportable private key - PKCS#12

Do I need to utilize the PK maybe?

Thank you so much

Comment: *"it says that the certificate is not valid."* - if it says that then there appear to be an issue with your smartcard certificate. Please share the certificate (public information only), e.g. by sharing a PDF signed with your code.

Comment: I was thinking about it in the meantime. Is it possible that I need to use both certificates as a chain? At the moment I am using only the one out of two. Thank you

Comment: Btw, this is an example of an unsuccessfully signed PDF file https://docdro.id/M8pGcyD

Comment: Which iTextSharp version do you use? Your code looks like it should create a proper adbe.pkcs7.detached signature embedding a CMS signature container using SHA256 as digest algorithm. Your example file, on the other hand creates a adbe.x509.rsa_sha1 signature without a certificate. Are you sure the code you show above really is executed and not some different code?

Comment: In particular: You call `MakeSignature.SignDetached`. According to its code that method embeds a CMS container, never a naked PKCS#1 signature. But your sample document contains no CMS signature container but instead something that might be a PKCS#1 signature.